# How to set filter to AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, adapter, autocompletetextview, textwatcher

I have some data in in arrayList allDoctorsAndSpecialities.

In my Oncreate method I have set adapter and threshold(3) for my autotxt(AutoCompleteTextView)

However,My problem is I don't want to show dropdown for strings entered in edittext like "dr.","dr. ",etc.

Following are solutions I tried

1) code:

```
autotxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }             

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(autotxt.getText().toString().equals("dr.")){
                autotxt.dismissDropDown();
            }
        }
    });
```

Problem- It does not work combination like 'Docname DocSurname'

2)[AutoCompleteTextView filter problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570764/autocompletetextview-filter-problem)

problem-It did not work for my problem

3)[How do I use publishResults() method when extending Filters in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067446/how-do-i-use-publishresults-method-when-extending-filters-in-android/11204620#11204620)

problem-I dont understand how to set constraint for performFiltering method

Please suggest me how to proceed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it via array adapter filter.

Comment: do I need to call performFiltering method manually??
I tried it as well my 2nd link bt not worked

Comment: No not in the text watcher. Try in filter in arrray adapter. Refer this for use of filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050108/android-autocompletetextview-using-arrayadapter-and-filter

Comment: Hi llango,
I solved the problem by customizing my AutocompleteTextView
refered this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/OrsN2xRpDmA
In my case performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) method was not getting called but will try it out once more